# Required attribute is not working for forms

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

As a small beginner project for HTML, CSS and Javascript, I was tasked with making a website for a restaurant. However, when I tried using the `required` attribute in an `input` tag, it didn't work. Here is the page with the problems:

HTML:

```html
  <form name = "loyalty1">
                <section id = "teal1">
                    <h2> Teal Level </h2>
                    <p> Get $10 off for every third meal (must be above $50) from the restuarant. Get exclusive discounts for new meals. Price: $20 /month.</p>
                    <div id = "checkbox" style = "background-color: none">
                      <input type = "checkbox" id = "teal">
                      <label for ="teal" style = "margin-left: 0px"> Buy Teal Level </label>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id = "aqua1">
                    <h2> Aqua Level </h2>
                    <p> Get $15 off for every third meal (must be above $50) from the restaurant. Not only will you get exclusive discounts for new meals, and you will recieve amazing recipies! Price: $40/month.</p>
                    <div id = "checkbox" style = "background-color: none">
                      <input type = "checkbox" id = "aqua" >
                      <label for ="aqua" style = "margin-left: 0px"> Buy Aqua Level </label>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section id = "turquoise1">
                    <h2> Turquoise Level </h2>
                    <p> Get one meal free for every 3 meals above $50. You will also recieve exclusive discounts, new meals and attend private cooking and baking classes from our chefs! Price: $60/month. </p>
                    <div id = "checkbox" style = "background-color: none">
                      <input type = "checkbox" id = "turquoise">
                      <label for ="turquoise" style = "margin-left: 0px"> Buy Turquoise Level </label>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <div style = "display: inline; margin: 15px 580px">
                  Email: <input type = "email" name = "userEmail" required>
                  <input type="submit" onclick="loyalty()" style = "margin: 15px 620px">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Javascript function:

```js
function loyalty(){
  var email = document.loyalty1.userEmail.value;

  else
  {
    if ((document.getElementById("teal").checked == false) && (document.getElementById("aqua").checked == false) && (document.getElementById("turquoise").checked == false))
    {
      alert("Please select a loyalty level.")
    }
    else if (((document.getElementById("teal").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("aqua").checked == true)) || ((document.getElementById("teal").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("turquoise").checked == true)) || ((document.getElementById("aqua").checked == true) && (document.getElementById("turquoise").checked == true))) {
      alert ("Please select only one loyalty level.")
    }
    else if (document.getElementById("teal").checked == true)
    {
          alert ("Thank you for choosing the Teal loyalty level. We will email you at " + email + " for further instructions.")
     }
    else if (document.getElementById("aqua").checked == true) {
        alert ("Thank you for choosing the Aqua loyalty level. We will email you at " + email  + " for further instructions.")
      }
    else if (document.getElementById("turquoise").checked == true) {
        alert ("Thank you for choosing the Turquoise loyalty level. We will email you at " + email + " for further instructions.")
    }
  }
}
```

On a different page on my website, the `required` attribute is working just fine, which is really confusing:

```js
function feedback() {
  var email = document.feedback.userEmail.value;
  var comments = document.feedback.comment.value;

  if (comments == "")
  {
    alert("Please fill in the comment field.")
  }

  alert ("Thank you for your feedback. \n" + "Email: " + email + "\nComment: " + comments);
}
```

```html
<form name = "feedbackForm" id = "feedback">
                    <p> Please enter your email: </p>
                    <input type = "email" id = "userEmail" required>

                    <p> Please enter your feedback: </p>
                    <textarea rows = "4" columns = "50" name = "comment" form = "feedback">Enter text here</textarea>

                    <input type = "submit" style = "margin: 15px 620px" onclick = "feedback()">
                </form>
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me when I click the `Run code snippet` button, I'm running FireFox. If I enter an invalid e-mail address I get a tooltip saying to enter an e-mail and if I enter a valid e-mail the page works.

Comment: What do you exactly want to happen? The `required` attribute in your code works for me, if I leave `<input type="email"`... blank it doesn't let me submit the form.

Comment: Thats extremely weird, it doesn't work for me. I will try again. However, I was wondering if the `required` attribute will work for `<input type = "number' >` tags

Comment: The function loyalty has an incomplete `else`-block in the second row. this is propably not what you intend to do.

Comment: Did you try to use the `onsubmit` handler on the form? This should do the job for you, because the submit is triggerd after validation and before submitting the form.

Comment: @Steven Thank you for the catch on the else block. It seems that the `on submit` handler was the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

the required field in you code is working fine! 
i would advice you to change the checkbox to radio this will save you from checking if the user selected only one item (radio button don't allow selecting 2 radio with the same name)